# How can I manage performance of the Bing Maps control wihtin a universal app?

Tags: c#, performance, windows-store-apps, bing-maps, win-universal-app

I've added the Bing Maps control to a Windows Store App (Strictly speaking, by following the steps on [Ricky Brunditt's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rbrundritt/archive/2014/06/24/how-to-make-use-of-maps-in-universal-apps.aspx)).

I've noticed (with the help of the [profiling tools in Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/02/27/how-to-profile-a-xaml-windows-store-app.aspx) that my app has CPU usage spikes, even after closing it. The profiler suggests that the usage is coming from the Bing Maps control on a 30 second cycle, and this seems to be exacerbated when the Bing Maps control is within a FlipView (as it's creating an instance of the Map for each item in the FlipView)

Is there some way to stop the control from using so much CPU time, when the control is not visible?

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended to not use the map in pages/flipview type controls as this will create multiple instances of the map control. Every time the map is created it generates a new transactions which goes against your free usage. Also, the map control is a very heavy control that does a lot of processing and contains a lot of data. What a number of developers have done is created a single instance of the map control on the main page and then would hide/show, resize, and reposition as needed depending on the view. Often they would create a control the inherits from a grid or canvas as a stand-in for where the map goes and when that control loads it would move the map accordingly.

Comment: *How* would you suggest doing this? Would a virtualising stackpanel in the flipview help? I was surprised to see the control using lots of CPU time, even after closing the app.

Comment: This recommendation comes from the Bing Maps team and is not a critique. 

Usually creating the control on the main page and creating a static variable that exposes it is a good start. From there a control that looks for this static variable and positions/resizes it can be included in views. I've done this a few times before and a hope to find some time soon to put together a blog post on how to do this.